# Disable vector wrapping in ol3 >= v3.5.0

Tags: openlayers-3

I just upgraded to ol3 v3.5.0 in the application I'm developing.  I noticed that now, vector features are shown in each "wrapped map" (dunno how to call it), which is very nice!

Is there a way to disable this, though ?  In a tool I developed, I manipulate some browser event coordinates on dragged vector features.  This only works in the main "map", but not in the others.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wrapX false on the source see: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html

Comment: Yep, that was it !  Thanks, Bart.